# How to count a specfic word in json file

Tags: json, powershell

I am having difficulty in writing a PowerShell script which reads through a JSON file and counts the occurrence of a specific word.

For example, if I have a JSON block like this:

```
"Cars": [
    {
      "CardId": "1234df",
      "CareName": "Audi",
      "registration": RGY17Q,


    },
    {
       "CardId": "12897gh",
      "CareName": "Audi A5",
      "registration": R98jkj,
```

How do I count how many `Cars` blocks there are and how many car IDs names there are within the `Cars` block in the whole document?

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. Please try to solve the problem yourself first and come back when you have a *specific* question about something that's not working as you expect.

Comment: this is what i wrote but cannot figure out how to read from a file and count for a specfic word, at the moment its just reading from $a  $a= "carid"
 
([regex]::Matches($a, "carid" )).count

Comment: Combine `get-content`, `select-string` and `measure-object` cmdlets.

Comment: i have combined the cmdlets but the problem is "Cars" is in double quotation already in the document but when i run the command i get an error with regards to Quotes $json |Get-Content |Select-String -pattern ""Cars":"| measure | select -exp count

Comment: if i take the double quotes off from "Cars" within the document i do get the count but the problem is i have to search with the double quotes in the above script

Comment: Parsing the content manually is the long way around. Look at `Convertfrom-JSON` to turn it into a collection of objects which you can then process efficiently.

Comment: Hi i can count the items now. All i would like to do is , i want to add a string with shows Cars = 10 because at the moment i am only able to view the number of cars e.g 10...the script which i am using is this $json |Get-Content |Select-String -pattern "Cars"| measure | select -exp count

Comment: If you have a new question, post a new question - don't amend your existing one.